# How to specialized a variadic argument method defined inside a variadic templated class?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, specialization

I have a variadic templated class which contains a method with variadic arguments.
I would like to specialize the method depending on some of the parameters provided with a specialized version of the class.

I know how to specialize variadic argument functions and how to perform template specialization. Unfortunately, I have not managed to use both specializations together.

My current solution seems to be overriding the solution which is not what I want.
Below is the simplified problem

```
    #include <iostream>

struct X;
struct Y;

template<typename ... FooTs>
struct Foo
{
public:

  template < typename... Ts >
  static int value(Ts... args){ return 0;};

};

template <>
struct Foo<X,Y>{
    static int value(int& a, int& b, float& c)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized value 3 args..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};

/* Ideally I would also like to have such specialization
template <>
struct Foo<X,Y>{
    int value(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized value 2 args..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};*/

int main(){
    Foo<X, Y> foo;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    float c = 3.4;
    Foo<X,Y>::value(a, b, c);
    foo.value(a, b, c);
    // foo.value(a, b);  // error: no matching function for call to 'Foo<X, Y>::value(int&, int&)
    return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve the specialization of the "value" method on the example above?

Comment: Why don't you want to overload the member function? Seems like a reasonable way to solve the problem.

Comment: Just put two-parameter `value` into the first `struct Foo<X,Y>` definition, alongside the three-parameter `value`. It would be a plain vanilla pair of overloaded functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be be single `Foo<X,Y>` type.

Because of this, you cannot specialize `Foo` itself based on the template parameters of one of its functions. Think about it: What would happen if `Foo` had multiple templated functions inside of it?

However, you can create a specialized version of the function like you are asking by overloading the **function** itself instead of the type:

```
template<>
template<>
int Foo<X, Y>::value(int a, int b) {
    return 12;
}

int test() {
    return Foo<X,Y>::value(1,2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solves my main question. On a bit more specific note, is it possible to keep the static attribute of the method once specialized?... If I add the "static" keyword on the specialization I have an error due to static linkage.

Comment: The static attribute is a property of the declaration, not the definition. So not only do you keep it, you can't get rid of it.

Comment: Indeed, I missed to try it before adding the static keyword, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with templates, or specialization. It's simple, really:

```
template <>
struct Foo<X,Y>{
    static int value(int& a, int& b, float& c)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized value 3 args..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int value(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << "specialized value 2 args..." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7jhKK6)

Comment: Thanks Igor and @cigien. I expected a more general approach. I will use the class as a base class, hence specializations are not known to be known at this stage. For the sake of making the problem specific I brought those two options. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: Well, explain what you are trying to achieve, there's likely a way to achieve it. I for one can't read your mind and discern the real problem you are trying to solve.